# Angular2 Form using setValue to reset value to null

Tags: angular2-template, angular2-forms

**Sorry for this question. This is to do with one of my child component which rejecting null, empty string while writing to form.**

I have a form control orderNo. 
When I try to do
    `this.myForm.controls['orderNo'].setValue = '123';`
It works fine and my view is updated with this value.
 But the issue is, I am not able to set the control with null or empty string. Whenever I do
    `this.myForm.controls['orderNo'].setValue = null;`
    or
    `this.myForm.controls['orderNo'].setValue = '';`
it doesn't reflect on my view. 
But I could see the form control holds that null value.  (ng.probe($0).componentInstance.myForm.controls['orderNo'].value returns null).
 It is just not being reflected on the view.

Please help me with some thoughts. Thank you.

Comment: Yeah that's weird, Could you show the code for the form and the view?

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Just now realised, this has nothing to do with angular2 formcontrol. I have a child component which sets the value of all the control. And on its WritValue() method, It has a condition if(value) { this.value = value; }. That was rejecting my null and empty string.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can directly use patchValue to set value of form fields

```js
    this.myForm.patchValue( {'orderNo':null} );
```

Answer (score 8):

Below resets entire formgroup to null

```js
    this.myForm.reset();
```

Comment: If you've directives attached to your formcontrols they will not working properly after a reset.